# Java: Code ownership visualization

Tags: java, ide, visualization, javadoc

What are tools to see code ownership in the project?

Every Java class have `@author` in the JavaDoc class comment.
So it is possible to count number of lines of every class and summarize in how many lines every author has.

Example could be [TreeMap](https://analysis.apache.org/dashboard/?did=6) showing size of projects, or packages (if clicked). See running Sonar instance at https://analysis.apache.org/ I would like to see similar TreeMap for authors.

We actually have [Collective code ownership](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CodeOwnership.html), but I have idea of company-level hard-coder contest to encourage developers commit often and configure Jenkins jobs etc.

UPDATE: rephrasing question: Is there way to see lines of code committed per contributor in selected period? UPDATE 2: Visual solution is needed, looking only on those numbers may be dull.

Comment: Are you suggesting that if I wrote 100 lines of code and you wrote 900 (of a 1000 line project), you own 90% (or for that matter did 90% of the work)? First -- there's much more to "owning" code than just writing the lines, and second, not all lines of code are created equal.

Comment: If you have "collective code ownership", then don't call whatever you are measuring "code ownership", or you're shooting yourself in the foot. Call it "lines of code commited" or "builds broken" or "lines-produced-to-meet-arbitrary-values" or something like that.

Comment: Have you quick guys read question completely and understood it? I am absolutely agree that such approach to measure productivity is pointless, and that comparing those numbers gives you no real value. It is just for fun!

Comment: @mah upvote on comment, because misquoting Thomas Jefferson makes it awesome.

Comment: Software Engineering 101, first class: "What's the only metric you shouldn't use when doing code revision? Lines per programmer!". But if you insist, you could use `git blame` (or the equivalent for your RCS), although I don't see the *fun* in doing something like this :/

Comment: Quote "git-blame - Show what revision and author last modified each line of a file" That is really too strong. Notation of @author was introduced to answer question quickly "Who can help with this code?"

Comment: So I actually have problem to encourage developers to add this simple javaDoc @author to indicate that they are ready to answer questions.

Answer (score 2):

You kind of answered your question yourself. If you want to see committed lines, you can use your version control system for that. For instance, with svn, there is an [svn log](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html) command and [svnstat](http://svnstat.sourceforge.net/), [statsvn](http://www.statsvn.org/) tools based on it. Also see Maven's [stat-scm plugin](http://stat-scm.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Updated my answer with few more links.

Answer (score 0):

> So I actually have problem to encourage developers to add this simple
>   javaDoc @author to indicate that they are ready to answer questions.

Here is the relevant documentation how to access Javadoc tags:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/index.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/javadoc/doclet/

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/javadoc/doclet/com/sun/javadoc/package-summary.html#package_description

Comment: This is not answer, but seems useful.